# Placing Vbox es

Tags: boxes, multicol

I am writing a text using LaTeX. I want my test to be 2-columned. I have done this using `multicols` environment. My question's text and its choices mustn't be splitted by a page break, or column break. So I have used put my code inside `\vbox`. Now I want to align my questions automatically. The free space in each column must be shared equally between questions. So how can I achieve this?

Here is an example for what I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \noindent
        \vbox
        {
            Question content
        } \\
        \vbox
        {
            Question content
        } \\
        \vbox
        {
            Question content
        } \\
        \vbox
        {
            Question content
        } \\
        \vbox
        {
            Question content
        } \\
        \vbox
        {
            Question content
        }\\
    \end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

As you will be able to see in output, spaces between `\vbox` s are not distributed equally, and looks ugly. Note: I mean vertical axis.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In particular, it would be very helpful to know which `documentclass` you're using, because this may change the answers.

Comment: Remove the ``\\`` after the last question, or else it breaks it up as 4 Q on the left and 2Q+blank Q on the right.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you're describing.  Are you referring to vertical spaces or horizontal spaces? [Here's what I see.](http://i130.photobucket.com/albums/p263/abc124_photos/vboxes_zpsaa75891d.png)

Comment: Vertical spaces.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bMy2e.png This image describes what I want. Red boxes are questions. Gray space between questions must be shared equally in a column. The maximum number of red boxes must be inserted each column.

Comment: I'm still confused. That's what you've achieved, as long as you take out the extra linebreak you have. Perhaps you need a more complex MWE to show the problem?

Comment: Should the title of this posting possibly be changed to "Placing vboxes", to more accurately represent the objective?

Comment: `\vboxes` will align at baseline and hence the problems you experiencing. Rather post what you trying to achieve, so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

The use of `\vboxes` is inappropriate for what you are trying to achieve, that is balanced columns.

`\vboxes` and `\parboxes` or `\minipages` in TeX are containers with unbreakable content. It is better to use lists to format your text of questions.

The following minimal demonstrates the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\def\story#1#2{%
 \leavevmode
   \colorbox{#1}{\parbox{\columnwidth-\columnsep}{#2}}%
  }
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{2}

        \story{orange!50}{\lipsum[1]}

        Question content

        \fbox{\story{black!20}{\lipsum[7]}}   

       Question content


       \story{orange!30}{\lipsum[8]}

       Question content

       Question content

    \end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As the framed box cannot be fitted at the bottom of the column, LaTeX moves it to the right column, then when the columns are balanced, you get the ugly layout you have mentioned. Better post a new question with an example of what you are trying to achieve.